# How to list directories differently as normal files in Bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm looking for a bash script that reads a file and checks if it's a regular file or a directory.

If it is readable, displays the file, but if it is a directory, it lists the directory.

My goal is to handle files and directories in Unix with the same tool / software API.

Answer (score 0):

The script is trivial. Important to know, that it also checks if they are symbolic links (thus, in the case of a symlink, it won't work correctly).

```
if [ -f "$1" ]
then
  echo "$1"
elif [ -d "$1" ]
then
  ls "$1"
else
  echo "$1 does not exist" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

You can include it into a function of a shellscript, or you can make it into a different tool.

The [manual page of the bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) is only complex for the first spot, actually it has a very clear structure and the bash isn't so complex to be not easy to learn.

Comment: He might want `cat "$1"` for files instead of `echo "$1"`, but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: @chepner Yes... afaik something could (should) be done with questions like this.